# Корректная структура\архитектура проекта ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, архитектура

Из-за того, что перескакивал с одного на другое, запутался в том, как правильно должен быть устроен проект на ASP.NET Core. Возник ряд вопросов

1. Сервис это простой класс со своими методами, который лежит в папке Services?
2. Весь ли функционал за исключением маршрутизации должен быть заключен в сервисах?
3. Чем они отличаются от микросервисов?
4. Слышал что-то про слои приложения, но не понимаю тоже, как они правильно организуются и актуально ли это сейчас?
5. Как правильно разделять клиентскую часть приложения и серверную?

Я пробовал искать, но везде как-то по-разному пишут и я не понимаю, что используют сейчас, как все-таки правильно это делать и оптимально. Если можно, поделитесь либо информацией, либо ссылками на ресурс, где правильно это расписано.
Или может быть, проект на гитхабе, в котором хорошая структура

Comment: Понятия "правильная архитектура" нет в природе. Каждый проект чем то да отличается. Где то можно сделать одни допущения, где то другие. Потому вы и не можете найти ответ на свой вопрос - его просто не существует. Есть некоторые рекомендации, типа паттернов или архитектурных шаблонов, есть рекомендации по написанию кода, есть рекомендации по написанию классов. Но это только рекомендации, а не жесткие правила.

Comment: `Чем они отличаются от микросервисов?` если бы вы хотя бы мало мальски подготовились, почитали бы любую информацию по микросервисам, то смогли бы ответить на этот вопрос самостоятельно.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.CleanArchitecture

Comment: @tym32167 благодарю за ответ. По поводу микросервисов, правда зря написал, прошу прощения, их не изучал, не знаю, на что рассчитывал. А вот остальное в самом деле интересно и неоднозначно для меня, просто не могу определиться, как лучше создавать приложение: чтобы это один проект был или один для сервера, другой для клиента и тд. Потому что до этого я просто все в контроллерах писал и думал, что это нормальная практика.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете себя "как правильно сделать?" - это неверный вопрос. Когда у вас есть разные опции, вам надо каждую из них рассмотреть, понять плюсы и минусы, и на основе этого выбрать наиболее вам подходящую. Вот вы не знаете, разделять ваш проект или нет. А Вы спросите себя, так ли сильно связан клиент с сервером, чтобы держать их вместе? Как много у них общих классов? Можно ли уменьшить сложность вашего проекта, выделив отдельно клиента, отдельно сервер, отдельно общие классы?

Comment: Вообще в чем суть проекта? Проект - это, по сути, набор связанного по смыслу кода. Пример: проект с бизнес логикой, проект с интеграционными тестами, проект с фронтендом, проект с бекендом и т.д. Подумайте, зачем программисты вообще разделяют код на проекты, можно же просто все в одну кучу свалить. Как только это поймете, примените это знание на ваш проект и решите, будет вам какой то профит от разделения на несколько проектов или нет.